# how to implement analytics in spring integration project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am working on Spring Integration Project and I want to implement analytics. Basic idea is to capture method name, timestamp and number of times called in all gateways.

Is there any default package / class available to log these details?

Here is what I thought to do and need to suggestion before I proceed further

> **Step 1 :** Add method name is gateway method header

```
<int:gateway id="gateway" service-interface="org.pro.gateway.SampleGateway">
    <int:method name="method1" request-channel="request.input.channel" reply-channel="reply.output.channel">
        <int:header name="methodName" value="placeOrder"/>
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
```

> **Step 2 :** Add Spring Wire tap interceptor, apply pattern which matches only input channel. Get message header by name in the wiretap channel and log it.

```
<int:wire-tap channel="wiretapChannel" pattern="input*" />

<int:service-activator ref="analyticsBean" method="footprint" input-channel="wiretapChannel" output-channel="outputChannel"/>

<bean id="analyticsBean" class="org.pro.stat.AnalyticService"/>
```

> **Step 3 :** Implementation Code

```
public class AnalyticsService {
   public void footprint(Message<String> msg){
    String methodName = msg.getHeaders().get("methodName");  
    long timestamp = msg.getHeaders().getTimestamp();
    /* Send to some service / store it in file with incremented value */
    storeIt(methodName, timestamp);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your steps look good. 
However, why not make the Analytics Service use @Async (using task executor service in spring) thus not consuming load on your parent thread.